# PHP Get string between bracket tags

Tags: php

Why doesn't this work?

```
<?php

function GetBetween($var1="",$var2="",$pool) {

    $temp1 = strpos($pool,$var1)+strlen($var1);
    $result = substr($pool,$temp1,strlen($pool));
    $dd=strpos($result,$var2);

    if($dd == 0) {
         $dd = strlen($result);
    }

    return substr($result,0,$dd);
}

$str = "[id]159828[/id][name][/name]";

$str =  GetBetween("[name]","[/name]",$str);

echo $str;
?>
```

Returns:

```
[/name]
```

Works fine if there is something in there. I need it to return NOTHING if its not found.

Thanks!

Comment: If nothing is between those fields `$dd` is first equal to 0 and then changed to be the length of the result. This makes your final call `substr($result,0,7)`. If you have a value between the name brackets `$dd` is never set to 0 and the secondary assignment does not happen. Get rid of the `if($dd == 0)...` block.

Comment: No use setting default values for `$var1` and `$var2` if `$pool` is a required parameter of `GetBetween()`. Put `$pool` as the first parameter if you want to make the others optional.

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine up until `$result`. You have:

```
$result = substr($pool,$temp1,strlen($pool));
```

We have `$temp1 = 15`, and `strlen($pool) = 22`, so this is equivalent to:

```
$result = substr("[id]159828[/id][name][/name]", 15, 22)
```

You may want to omit the `$length` argument here, so that `substr` just returns the remainder of the string after position 15. Either way, `$result` is equal to `"[/name]"`.

This means that `$dd` is going to equal 0, since the `strpos` of `"[/name]"` in `$result` is at the very beginning. The `if()` statement then changes `$dd` to `strlen($result)`, which is 7. Then, the return value is `substr($result,0,$dd)`, or `$substr("[/name]",0,7)`, which evaluates to `"[/name]"`.

To fix this, you need to **remove the `if()` statement entirely.**

That way, `$dd` is left at zero, so the `return` value is a substring of zero length, which is what you wanted: an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

just add this check:

```
if(substr($pool, strpos($pool, $var1), strlen("$var1$var2")) == "$var1$var2")
return false;
```

Then:

```
function GetBetween($var1="",$var2="",$pool) {
    if(substr($pool, strpos($pool, $var1), strlen("$var1$var2")) === "$var1$var2"){
      return false;
    }
    $temp1 = strpos($pool,$var1)+strlen($var1);
    $result = substr($pool,$temp1,strlen($pool));
    $dd=strpos($result,$var2);

    if($dd == 0) {
         $dd = strlen($result);
    }

    return substr($result,0,$dd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to match the stuff between two values. For example

```
function between($v1, $v2, $str){
    $v1 = preg_quote($v1, '~');
    $v2 = preg_quote($v2, '~');
    if(preg_match("~$v1(.*)$v2~", $str, $tmp)){
       return $tmp[1];
    }else{
       return "";
    }
}
```

Or even without empty return since `$tmp[1]` will be `null` if there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

If you're always parsing the same format, you can try a `sscanf()`

It's quite nice for defining a format then reading variables out without using regular expression matching.

eg.

```
$str = "[id]159828[/id][name][/name]";
sscanf($str, "[id]%d[/id][name]%[^[/name]]", $id, $name);
```

$id and $name will be populated with the (even empty) values.